# Jquery carousel dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm using owl-carousel jquery plugin and instafeedjs. When instafeedjs run, owl-carousel didn't see sub elements. when i try find elements (which class instaImg) with length function, it's return 0. But i'm sure it have 27 element. How i can find elements? I think problem is instafeed create elements after page loading but i try setTimeOut() it's still return 0.

Does anybody have any suggestion or easy plugin?

Code :

```js
 var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awsome',
        clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  template: '<div class="instaImg"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></div>',
  resolution : 'thumbnail'
    });
    feed.run();

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var count =$('.instaImg').length; 
 console.log(count);   
});
```

```css
<div id="instafeed" class="instaThings" style="width:9999999px;"></div>
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/master/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place Your Instafeed part inside document ready handler.
You were calling instafeed before  loaded.
That's why when instafeed tried to do:

```
document.getElementById('instafeed')
```

it stopped with failure.

So here is solution:

```js
$(function(e) {
  var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'instafeed',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'awsome',
    clientId: 'bf6f84fcd7d643daa915f14a5fef657e',
    template: '<div class="instaImg"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></div>',
    resolution : 'thumbnail'
  });
  feed.run();
  var count =$('.instaImg').length; 
  console.log(count);   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/master/instafeed.min.js"></script>

<div id="instafeed" class="instaThings" style="width:9999999px;"></div>
```